# I am not able to connect to internet under bridge adapter in ubuntu using vbox

Tags: virtualbox, internet, connection, ip, ping

I have used Bridge Adapter in Vbox
Earlier I could connect but over a period of time IP address of Vbox kept increasing by 1 and then it displayed no IP address
Now after reinstalling Vbox, I got a IP address but unable to connect to Internet.